# How to get __init__() to raise a more useful exception instead of TypeError when incorrect # of arguments?

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I have a class with an **init** that takes many arguments--some required, some not.

If one of the needed arguments is not supplied, you may get a TypeError, with an unhelpful message like 'requires at least 10 arguments (14 given)'.

I would like to have a custom TypeError subclass that actually informs the user of which arguments are missing.

Comment: Are these keyword arguments or positional?

Comment: @zwol kwargs (that can be supplied positionally).

Comment: @zwol, that being said... all arguments are named arguments. The function shouldn't care if they are supplied as kwargs or positionally, it should know which one is missing according to itself either way, no?

Comment: I ask because there's a simple thing you can do now if they're all keyword arguments and you can use Python 3.  Positionals are harder.

Comment: @zwol ah. Our codebase is 2.7, though I'm still interested in hearing about it.

Comment: The "simple thing" in Py3 is mandatory keyword-only arguments as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use kwargs, you can set in **init** a list of required arguments and then check if all required kwargs are present. Check out the following example.

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        required_args = ['arg_1', 'arg_2']

        for arg in required_args:
            if arg not in kwargs:
                raise TypeError("Argument %s is required" % arg)

obj = Something(arg_1=77, arg_3=2)
```

Comment: While I had to edit this answer to be a little more efficient, and then needed to rewrite it to be a bit more robust and provided that below, it seemed more appropriate to 'accept' this one... But if you're planning on actually implementing this, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, you can define a function that takes "required keyword-only arguments."  This is clearest documented in [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).  The error message you get when you omit required keyword-only arguments includes the argument names.

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2rc1 (default, Jun 13 2016, 09:33:26) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> class X:
...   def __init__(self, *, foo, bar, baz):
...     self.foo = foo
...     self.bar = bar
...     self.baz = baz
... 
>>> a = X(foo=1,bar=2,baz=3)
# no error
>>> b = X(foo=1,bar=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'baz'
>>> b = X(foo=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'bar' and 'baz'
```

However, this is not compatible with code that expects to be able to call `X()` with *positional* arguments, and the error message you get is still the one you don't like:

```
>>> a = X(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Also, this feature is not available in any version of Python 2:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12rc1 (default, Jun 13 2016, 09:20:59) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class X(object):
...    def __init__(self, *, foo, bar, baz):
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    def __init__(self, *, foo, bar, baz):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Improving the diagnostics given for positional arguments would probably involve hacking the interpreter.  The Python development team might be amenable to patches; I'd consider bringing this up on the [python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas) mailing list.

Comment: I actually will join that list and suggest it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a variation off of [Tomas Gonzalez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981082/4526479), rewriting it so that it supports the mixture of ordered args, keyword args, and default values that existed. This supported our requirement of writing code that is always backwards compatible with legacy code. For 'greenfield' implementations, Tomas' answer is preferable (and one would just always make calls with kwargs). For legacy situations like mine (or ones wherein a combination of ordered required and non-required arguments may be necessary?), consider the following:

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    required_args = ['a', 'b']

    # to support legacy use that may included ordered args from previous iteration of this function
    ordered_args = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

    default_args = {
        'c': 0,
        'd': 1,
        'e': 2
    }

    for index, value in enumerate(args):
        kwargs[ordered_args[index]] = value

    for arg in required_args:
        if arg not in kwargs:
            raise TypeError("Argument %s is required" % arg)

    for arg in default_args:
        if arg not in kwargs:
            kwargs[arg] = default_args[arg]
```

While this is an acceptable hack, I was really hoping to subclass the native TypeError raised, so that the original function would still look 'normal'.